# PHP login works on localhost and adds users on live site, but doesnt retrieve passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login system that works fine on my localhost. When I uploaded it to my live database I can create a user and it will input the data into the database, but when I try to login it doesn't seem to find the password. When I echo the values from the live database it gives nothing for `$realpass['password'];`

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$conn = mysql_connect($_SESSION['db_name'], $_SESSION['db_username'], $_SESSION['db_password'] );
mysql_select_db($_SESSION['db_table'], $conn);

//Get Password
$query = "SELECT `password` FROM `user` WHERE email_address='$username';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$realpass = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(sha1($password)!=$realpass['password'])
{
    echo "Error! Invalid username or password, please try again.<br/>";
    echo sha1($password)."<br/>";
    echo $realpass['password'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't use `sha1` without salts...

Comment: It was just for a project, so there was no need to salt it and really no need to hash it either

Comment: Even tho it's just for a project, it's still good to get into good practices and not use `mysql_*` functions, since they're deprecated...

Comment: It's fine that this is for a project, but code like this has a way of weaselling its way into production without you looking. Like a loaded gun, it's a very bad idea to leave it laying around. You're doing zero [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) which makes this doubly hazardous. I hope you don't mind your project database being downloaded by anyone with a [SQL exploit tool](http://sql-map.org/).

Comment: If it was just for a project, why bother putting a (buggy) password system in the first place? OW, and storing passwords and stuff in sessions?

Comment: Well shouldn't `'$username'` be in double quotes? I'm pretty sure your actually searching for literally `$username`. Also SHA1 has been proved to be week like @user3444414 said. You should be using a stronger function and salting your hashes to prevent against lookup attacks. Also, @tadman he is actually escaping the username, which is the only user provided data in the query

Comment: @735Tesla No, `'$username'` should not be in double quotes, because the full string is already wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Add error handling to all database calls and you will probably see what's wrong.

Comment: @LeeSalminen Sorry didn't notice that

Comment: @LeeSalminen just read it again and I realized that was a really dumb thing to say. The single quotes are part of the query. Just had a hackathon yesterday with no sleep so I'm kind of out of it, sorry.

Comment: @735Tesla No worries :). I spent 4 hours working in Witango today. Worst. Language. Ever. Just don't want OP to get the wrong idea for his answer. I don't have a good one either though.

Comment: @stUrb How should I check if a user is logged in? Sessions seemed like a fine way to check at the time.

Comment: Store a random generated string in a session, and store the same random string in a db with a loggedin flag. Get the string from session, validate it in your database (via some checks: ip, user etc etc) and continue, or delete session.

Comment: My remark about storing passwords in a session was about storing the DB password + username in a session

Comment: Let's do some sanity checking... Firstly, can you please edit your question to include (before the `if`)... `print_r($realpass)`, and the same again if the query is modified to be `SELECT * FROM \`user\` WHERE email_address='$username';`. Can you also please use your database admin tool (I recommend [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)) to run the modified query and check the password is being stored as expected. Once we've got that, we should be able to narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);` is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

I changed it to `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);` and it works fine

Comment: However, you added *yet another* vulnerability to the system.

Comment: It doesn't really matter since the point of the project wasn't to have a secure application.

Comment: Then remove the password system entirely.  The illusion of security can be worse than the absence of security.

Comment: There's no illusion of security, the login system is just to allow you to save your preferences

Comment: Then you can remove the password and simply ask people who they are (although that won't fix your error or security vulnerability).  I urge (beg!) you to *never* write code with this kind of easy-to-avoid problem.  *Someone* else may see that code sometime, and you can judge from the response you're getting to your question what opinion they'll form.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Either you don't care, so shouldn't have a password or you _do_ care so should put some effort into it. Why bother having a password if you can log into a random account by having a username of `' OR 1=1 UNION ALL SELECT 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' ORDER BY 1;--` and a blank password? (you might need to jiggle the hash a few times to make sure it's the lowest value but...)

Comment: @Basic I deleted it because I wasn't sure why it was creating the error on the live web server. It didn't cause an error on my localhost, but seeing as no one here actually bothered to direct me to a proper solution, the simplest way around my problem was the delete the sanitizing.

Comment: @JoshM I can appreciate where you're coming from and I know this isn't always an easy topic. The reason for my negative tone is that I've dealt with so many people over the years who don't take security seriously that when I find someone whose answer is "I couldn't get it to work so I just deleted the security" that I get exasperated. For the sake of solving your problem (and avoiding a security cockup) let's see if we can track down your problem.. Out of space so I'll post a comment on the Q asking for some more info. If you want to get it working properly, I'm happy to spend the time helping

Answer (score 0):

In this depreciated case, I believe you are calling fetch array incorrectly.

Either use

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)[0]
```

or

```
mysql_fetch_row($result)[0]
```

To reference by name you need

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```